# How to find the end point in a mesh line. Blender Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I am attempting to create a dragon curve in Blender Geo nodes via duplicating and rotating a mesh line repeatedly, similar to this gif I found on wikipedia (without the beveling): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#/media/File:Dragon_Curve_unfolding_zoom_numbered.gif

## The Main Issue

I cannot find an easy way to locate the 'end' point in the mesh line, as shown in the gif. I've tried many different solutions, but all of them have failed. I check stack exchange multiple times and could not find a solution. I have hit a brick wall in terms of my very limited toolkit as I am quite new to Geo Nodes, and am still getting my footing. Feel free to ask further questions for more clarity on my part. Here are a few images showcasing my admittedly small problem.

[image: Current Node Setup. Things in the frame will be grouped and copy-pasted for the desired result]

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I know that there's already an answer, but just to let you know, Default Cube has uploaded a tutorial on this. https://youtu.be/gigIzivJkxk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example for independent study:

The generation method is to remember the start and end points, and overwrite them correctly for the next iteration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple and performant way to detect if a vertex is the "end" is to simply check the number of edges connected to it:

[image]

Comment: But how would I find the position of those points?

Comment: @Dreadward07 to find the position of them is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), you need to explain what is your end goal, because the most immediate answer to your question is simply: use the "Position" node.

Comment: Apologies, I should have made it clearer in my original question that I needed to return a vector for the end points.